# Skipping steps in Sql jobs on a particular day

Tags: sql-server

How to run the last step of Sql job skiping all the previous steps on a particular day? (Only on Friday the 1st 5 steps must be skipped and last step must run and in all other days of the week the job should run)

Comment: What have you tried already? Post your code

Comment: Create a separate job for Fridays, and don't run your normal job on a Friday.

Comment: In other words, you want different schedules. Create different jobs, each with its own schedule. It's a lot easier to implement, manage and monitor than try to code schedule variations in the language used by each step

Comment: Your script or whatever could check the day number (according to locale) and only run certain things conditionally. There are many ways to do this. Did you spend much time thinking what they might be before posting?

Comment: Nope. I want it under a single job. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: @underscore_d yep I did think. And so posted

Comment: @user9208802 then add logic in your statements to check the day, and don't run the rest of the batch if it's a Friday.

Comment: @user9208802 then either write the logic in every single step, or *explain* what language you use and why you want a single job, when you are trying to execute *TWO* jobs. A single complex job won't be easier to work with

Comment: Or you could create a maintenance plan instead of a job with date-based conditions on the links. Different jobs with different schedules would still be preferable

Comment: @Larnu I'm New to this technology and have got no idea about how to implement.

Comment: Use an `IF` statement at the start of the batch, and close it at the end of the batch. [IF...ELSE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql). You'll need to use `DATEPART` to get the weekday and a function to get the current date, such as `GETDATE()`, or `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`. Have a go yourself first, as you learn more by researching and trying out yourself,.

Comment: @Larnu should I write it under command inside each steps which I need to skip?

Comment: You'll need to to it in each step, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table which contains the dates on which a specific Step needs to be skipped and while executing the Step, check in the table whether the specific step is in the List to exclude for that date.

I Created 2 Table Like This

[image]

And Inserted Data Like This

[image]

Now each day, before executing a particular step just check the tables to see whether the Step is in the tables for that particular date.

As per this

- Step# 2 will be skipped on 12-Jan-2018
- Step# 3 will be skipped on 01-Feb-2018
- Step# 1 will be skipped on 28-Feb-2018

Comment: How long can I enter the date? It's a Sql scheduled job! All other steps must not run on friday

Comment: You can enter any date you wish. So it will be skipped on that date. There is no limit on SQL Server unless you have Less Storage Space on Disk